# Android ActionBar not Editable

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm designing an Android App and i have problem with the action bar of my app.
I've read so many tutorials,i've watched plenty of videos on youtube about this but still can't figure out the problem.
I want to edit my action bar so to add 2 more buttons.
Can someone help me?
I've used actionbarsherlock  but i want to run the App on my smartphone (Android 2.2 Froyo) and doesn't work...

Thanks in advance

Comment: "doesn't work" is a useless description of your symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the two MenuItems to your Options Menu, either in code or in xml, and make sure android:showInActionBar="always" (or "ifRoom") for them  then they appear in your Action Bar

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Although the problem was that i had to unzip the SherlockActionBar's folder on my eclipse folder..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following solution?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html